# IntelliJ IDEA new File(...) uses Workspace directory as root instead of git repository directory

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, resources

I just moved from Eclipse Luna to IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3 and I'm having a problem with creating a new File(...) object for a resource.
Here's my setup:

```
\dev\git\myproject\src\main\resources\myfile.txt is the resource I want to read
\dev\idea\workspace\myproject contains my IDEA project
```

This means I created an IDEA project in one directory and imported my (maven) project that resides in my git repository directory.
Now when I create a new File object using the following statement

```
inputFile = new File("src/main/resources/myfile.txt");
```

This will result in the following path:

```
\dev\idea\workspace\myproject\src\main\resources\myfile.txt
```

However, I would like to retrieve the resource from

```
\dev\git\myproject\src\main\resources\myfile.txt
```

Eclipse used to set the directory correctly but how can this be achieved with IDEA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with IntelliJ but with the way you try to access the file.

From your question, I can see that you use maven and you have a file in src/main/resources, which you like to access.

As per Maven, when you have a file in src/main/resources then it also means that the file will also available in classpath (see Maven folder structure to know more about it).

But you are trying to access the file using a relative path (which includes the maven folder structure) and this code will not work when you package your project. Since maven will exclude the folders(src/*/*) in the jar/war/ejb or any other package and only include the resources.

You should try to access the file from classpath which is the right way of doing it and also the most important thing is, it will work even after packaging your proejct.

Try replacing your code with,

```
inputFile = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myfile.txt").getFile());
```

or

```
inputFile = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("myfile.txt").getFile());
```

Use the above snippet based on the type of project, standalone or web app.

Comment: Thank you. The proposed solution works. The application was not ment to be packaged but only to be run from the IDE. I guess the difference between Eclipse and IntelliJ is that in an Eclipse workspace when you import an existing Maven application it uses the root directory of the Maven application as starting point whereas IntelliJ IDEA uses the project directory as starting point which doesn't have to be the same as the Maven application directory.